# Kettle - pan.sh "No repository provided, can't load transformation"

Tags: bash, pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

I've created a kettle transformation and i've tested on my pc and it works. However, i've insered it in the server and starting as bash script by pan.sh. It was working but after few times it started to give this problem.

```
server$ bash pan.sh file="API_Mining_LatestVersion.ktr"
#######################################################################
WARNING:  no libwebkitgtk-1.0 detected, some features will be unavailable
    Consider installing the package with apt-get or yum.
    e.g. 'sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0'
#######################################################################
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
14:56:00,682 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
14:56:00,803 INFO  [KarafInstance]
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 2 at /data/Fernando/data-integration_updated/./s ***
***   ystem/karaf/caches/pan/data-1                                         ***
*** FastBin Provider Port:52902                                             ***
*** Karaf Port:8803                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9052                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
Nov 20, 2018 2:56:01 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
*ERROR* [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=255, bundle=53/mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.manager/1.1.1]: Updating configuration org.apache.aries.transaction caused a problem: null
org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: null : null
        at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerService.<init>(TransactionManagerService.java:136)
        at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.Activator.updated(Activator.java:63)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:148)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:81)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1448)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1404)
        at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.objectweb.howl.log.LogConfigurationException: Unable to obtain lock on /data/Fernando/data-integration/system/karaf/caches/pan/data-1/txlog/transaction_1.log
        at org.objectweb.howl.log.LogFile.open(LogFile.java:191)
        at org.objectweb.howl.log.LogFileManager.open(LogFileManager.java:784)
        at org.objectweb.howl.log.Logger.open(Logger.java:304)
        at org.objectweb.howl.log.xa.XALogger.open(XALogger.java:893)
        at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.HOWLLog.doStart(HOWLLog.java:233)
        at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerService.<init>(TransactionManagerService.java:133)
        ... 7 more
2018-11-20 14:56:04.508:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.15.v20140411
2018-11-20 14:56:04.544:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started NIOSocketConnectorWrapper@0.0.0.0:9052
[...]
INFO: New Caching Service registered
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/Fernando/data-integration_updated/launcher/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/Fernando/data-integration_updated/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2018/11/20 14:56:09 - Pan - Start of run.
ERROR: No repository provided, can't load transformation.
```

I don't understand where the problem is. The transformation file hasn't been changed and it contains also repo, user and pass paramethers.

Comment: Check the repository databse connection is accessible from the server. If the problem persist: what exactly is your pan.sh command (with fake password) ?

Comment: The org.osgi error are "normal" (as per Pentaho's opinion on best practice).

Answer (score 1):

I read on some docs somewhere that you need to give it the repo (even if you don't have one).

For example, I don't have a repo, and I call Pan like this (in Ubuntu WSL):

/mnt/c/Software/Pentaho/pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428/data-integration/pan.sh -rep: -file=SmokeTest.ktr